# CSS :not selector behavior

Tags: css, css-selectors

Using CSS, I'm trying to target all `ul` elements inside the `#include` element, except for the ones inside the `#exclude` element. Here's the markup:

```
<div id="include">
  <ul><li>Include List</li></ul>
  <div id="exclude">
    <ul><li>Exclude List</li></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I thought I could do this using the `:not` CSS selector like this:

```
#include :not(#exclude) ul {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

The result I'm seeing is that neither `ul` gets the blue color. Clearly I am misunderstanding how this `:not` selector works. Is what I'm trying to do possible?  Here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/flyingL123/gmpLgx4y/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `>` operator. This gets the immediate children of the element preceding. This will then get the `ul` immediately descending from `#include`. Updated:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7dwrap4f/1/)

Updated code:

```
#include > ul {
    color: blue !important;
}
```

You would **not** be able to to implicitly set styles by inheritance. They don't exclude ancestors because they don't trickle down. You will need to add new rules for other elements like so:

```
#include ul {
    color: blue;
}

#exclude ul {
    color: black;
}
```

Fiddle: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/t56Loqm1/)

Comment: This was just some sample code. On my real project the `ul` is not the immediate child. I want to target all `ul`'s within `#include` that are not within `#exclude` regardless of their depth. Is this not possible?

Comment: Edited @flyingL123

Comment: Yes, I see now from the docs for `:not` that this probably isn't possible the way I want to do it. `:not` doesn't trickle down to ancestors.

Comment: It doesn't. That's why it's not used for excluding ancestors. @flyingL123